# How to visualize the elements in one line in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following form:

```
    <h:form>    
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userRequestBean.selectedAgencyId}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" noSeletionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems
                value="#{userRequestBean.requestAgencies[userActiveRequest]}"
                var="agency" itemLabel="#{agency[0]}" itemValue="#{agency[1]}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <p:commandButton value="Hire"
            action="#{userRequestBean.hireAgency}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userRequestBean.request}"
                value="${userActiveRequest}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

and i would like the SelectOneMenu and Button to be on one line. I tried with panelGrid but the select one menu becomes invisible, the same happens when i tried to use the standard HTML table. Can you give me an advice how to put then on one line? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use panelGrid and play with `columns` option. If you have `N` components and you want to put them in one line set `columns` value to `N` like:

```
<h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="oneLineStyle">
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userRequestBean.selectedAgencyId}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" noSeletionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems
                        value="#{userRequestBean.requestAgencies[userActiveRequest]}"
                        var="agency" itemLabel="#{agency[0]}" itemValue="#{agency[1]}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <p:commandButton value="Hire"
                             action="#{userRequestBean.hireAgency}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userRequestBean.request}"
                                             value="${userActiveRequest}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Do you have some other ideas?